# OpenIDDict External Authentication from Facebook

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, openiddict

I've successfully got OpenIDDict working with a mix of cookie authentication and views for the website and Jwt Token Authentication for the APIs. Adapted solution to allow social media Facebook external logins. This works fine for Cookies and Views. But can't get openIdDicyt working for external login/authentication. I'm unsure what to do once I get the Facebook Authentication Token? I assume this is posted to /connect/token in the usual way but not sure what the settings should be?

I've tried:

```
grant_type: authorization_code; scope: openid offline_access; assertion: {Facebook token}
```

But this doesn't work.

Ideally, if someone has a postman screen dump of getting token from Facebook and another of what enteritis and where in postman usting this token to OpenIDDict through /connect/token

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rich Twitter Digits/Google Auth with OpenIdDictServer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223694/rich-twitter-digits-google-auth-with-openiddictserver)