# How to implement Facebook native app login in Ionic 3 with a .net Core API

Tags: asp.net-core, ionic3, openiddict

I have a .Net Core Auth API with OpenIddict and a .Net Core Api 'client'. Now I'm building an Ionic 3 native app and I want to implement Facebook login where people can login via the *native* Facebook app. So far I only found examples where the Facebook *web* login is used.

So far I have:

- a working .Net Core Auth API that returns Jwt tokens
- a working .Net Core Client API that accepts these JWT tokens
- a working Ionic 3 app that can login with username + password, get a token and use it.
- a working Ionic 3 app with a Facebook login that logs in via the *native* Facebook app (via Cordova plugin)

It feels like the Code flow is the correct way to go, but all examples redirects to the Facebook login *web* page so the user probably still has to log in on Facebook while his native Facebook app is already logged in.

My question is: after a user is logged in via Facebook in my Ionic app, how can I get a JWT Token from the OpenIddict Auth Api so I can use my client API? Or should I change the flow somehow while the native Facebook app is used to log in?

update: In Ionic I do get Facebook UserId which is equal to the AspNetUserLogins.ProviderKey. Is that secure enough to login to your Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the code flow or opening the system browser to complete the authentication process interactively (including the FB authentication step) is definitely not an option for you, consider using a custom grant to allow your mobile app to redeem a FB access token (or authorization code) with an access token issued by OpenIddict.

For more information, see this other SO thread: [Rich Twitter Digits/Google Auth with OpenIdDictServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223694/rich-twitter-digits-google-auth-with-openiddictserver)

Comment: thanks, I already was afraid that I had to take that route. I'll have a look to see if this can help me!