# ASP.NET Core 2.0 OpenIdDict with Facebook mobile application

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0, openiddict

Could you please provide me an example or description how to return an access token to the mobile application with facebook login.

Here is the workflow that I want to achieve:

1. Mobile user registers via Facebook
2. User is registered on the server database after successful Facebook login
3. OpenIdDict Access Token is returned from server to the mobile application

I have already implemented local user password workflow but cannot find any example of Facebook login via mobile app.

Comment: I am actually searching for the same. I'll get back to you when I get something. I just implemented the google auth using a server side validation, do you want to compare out implementations ?

Comment: This post describes an example of workflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623974/design-for-facebook-authentication-in-an-ios-app-that-also-accesses-a-secured-we?rq=1#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flow you describe is known as the "assertion grant". Read [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41224248/542757) for more information about how to implement it with OpenIddict.