# How to create an authenticate user with OpenIddict to retreive a Token to work with Integration Test

Tags: authentication, token, integration, openiddict

everyone,

I have a web api with OpenIddict Authentication.

- Core.Net 2.0 (C#),
- EntityFrameWorkCore 2.0

I would like to do integration test, but my controllers have Authorize atribute, so I need to have a autenticate user.

For my IT, I am using SQLite has an in-memory mode , [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite)

I don´t know howto create an user authenticate and retrieve the Token, that I need after to pass to the WebApi call.

Any advice?

Best regards.

Jolynice

Comment: i am stuck on this part, would be really helpful if you have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For a complete integration test, you could go with a custom grant type, as used in this other SO thread: [Rich Twitter Digits/Google Auth with OpenIdDictServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223694/rich-twitter-digits-google-auth-with-openiddictserver/41224248#41224248).

If you simply want to test your `[Authorize]`-protected actions, it's easier to mock `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>` and use it to set `OAuthValidationOptions.AccessTokenFormat`. You can take a look at [the aspnet-contrib validation handler tests](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Extensions/blob/dev/test/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation.Tests/OAuthValidationHandlerTests.cs) to see how it could be done using ASP.NET Core's `TestServer`.

Comment: Hi Pinpoint, thanks for the advice. I will try and I will come back to give my feedback.

Comment: @jolynice would you able to create integraion test using Open ID authentication ? if yes, can you provide details/.